# Extract part of a text according to one character or another

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to write a regex to get some part of a string depending to a character or another.

Here, all input I can have (size of each part is not fix-length):

```
1. aaaabbccc
2. aaaa-bbbb
3. bbbb/cccc
4. aaaa-bbbb/cccc
```

Rules are:

- if '-' exists = take right part of the '-' (case 2: `bbbb`)
- if '/' exists = take left part of the '/' (case 3: `bbbb`)
- if '-' and '/' exists = take part between '-' and '/' (case 4: `bbbb`)
- others = take all string (case 1: `aaaabbccc`)

I tried conditional regex like this: `(?(?=.*-.*)-[^\/]*|^[^\/]*)`

It almost work but the '-' is in the result and I don't want it.

Anybody have an idea?

Comment: I think you just need `Regex.Match(text, @"(?:^[^-]*-)?([^/]*)")?.Groups[1].Value`

Comment: Although regex sometimes saves many lines of code and it makes what we do simpler, however it is also slow, yours can be done in a few if-else with far much better performance.

Comment: Just contains and split should be enought.. You can even make it quite readable. have a simple datastructure for separator and target index. split on separator return the target index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer without Regex that should work way faster than the regex:

```
var dash = str.IndexOf("-");
var slash = str.IndexOf("/");
var result = dash != -1 ? 
(slash != -1 ? str.Substring(Math.Min(dash, slash) + 1, Math.Max(dash, slash) - Math.Min(dash, slash) -1) : str.Substring(dash + 1)):
(slash != -1 ? str.Substring(0, slash) : str);
```

Here is a live [DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/a8zkHz)

Here is the result from demo:

```
aaaabbccc
bbbb
bbbb
bbbb
```

Comment: You're right. I'm trying to make things complex but it's simple. I'll take this solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, skipping the complexity of Regex and simply translating your specification into C# may be a viable simple solution (and, it should be faster).  For example, taking your sample strings:

```
private static readonly string[] _testStrings =
{
    "aaaabbccc",
    "aaaa-bbbb",
    "bbbb/cccc",
    "aaaa-bbbb/cccc",
};
```

and running them through this code (which mimics your spec, ***Updated** after the comment by @DragAndDrop*):

```
foreach (var s in _testStrings)
{
    string result;
    var slashIndex = s.IndexOf("/");
    var hyphenIndex = s.IndexOf("-");
    if (slashIndex >= 0)
    {
        if (hyphenIndex >= 0)
        {
            result = s.Substring(hyphenIndex + 1, slashIndex - hyphenIndex - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            result = s.Substring(0, slashIndex);
        }
    } 
    else if (hyphenIndex >= 0)
    {
        result = s.Substring(hyphenIndex + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        result = s;
    }
    Debug.WriteLine(result);
}
```

results in:

```
aaaabbccc
bbbb
bbbb
bbbb
```

There's more code, but it's easier to read.  I'm also pretty sure that it will be faster to execute.

Comment: it's a string I think I would be nice with the new range operator. for example `result = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf("/"));` => `result = s[..s.IndexOf("/")]`; Can also get those index into helper variable to simplify `s.Contains("/")` and not iterate the string everytime looking for an index

Comment: Thanks @DragandDrop.  I don't have the latest C# handy, but reducing the `.Contains` calls is a great idea.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: Range is just syntaxe sugar. `Substring` is just as readable and straight forward. btw fixed one contains you missed.

Comment: Yeah, I saw your edit.  Thanks!  Code review is a beautiful thing.  I'm a big fan of nice clear code with short lines of code.  The accepted answer is nice, but I wouldn't want to pick it up for maintenance in 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 kind of separator `' '`, `'-'`, `'/'`.
You can split on them and take the part you want based on the index.

```
"1. aaaabbccc"      => "1", "aaaabbccc"
                        0      1

"2. aaaa-bbbb"      => "2.", "aaaa", "bbbb"
                        0      1       2

"3. bbbb/cccc"      => "3.", "bbbb", "cccc"
                        0      1       2

"4. aaaa-bbbb/cccc" => "4.", "aaaa", "bbbb", "cccc"
                        0      1       2       3
```

for example for input #4, the  `"bbbb"` part will be index 2

```
static string Spliter(string input)
{
    var rules = new   (char[] separators, int targetIndex)[] {
            (new []{' ', '-', '/' }, 2),
            (new []{' ', '/'}, 1),
            (new []{' ', '-'}, 2),
            (new []{' '}, 1),
        };

    foreach (var rule in rules) {
        if (rule.separators.Any() && rule.separators.All(separator => input.Contains(separator)))
            return input.Split(rule.separators)[rule.targetIndex];
    }

    return input;// default match no rules, return the input
}
```

result :

```
1. aaaabbccc        --> aaaabbccc
2. aaaa-bbbb        --> bbbb
3. bbbb/cccc        --> bbbb
4. aaaa-bbbb/cccc   --> bbbb
```

Demo : https://dotnetfiddle.net/dYxgN9

Imagine `"2. "` was never a part of your input. You simply drop the `' '` separtor and change the target index accordingly.